# Laravel Array key exists and containing data but returns nothing when accessing it

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, eloquent

I have a relationship between **Product** and **Photo** Models.

**Product** Model :

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\Product;
use App\Photo;

class Product extends Model
{
    public function photos() {
        return $this->hasMany(Photo::class, 'product_id');
    }
}
```

**Photo** Model :

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\Photo;
use App\Product;

class Photo extends Model
{
    public function product() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Product::class);
    }
}
```

When i get products like :

```
$product = Product::find($id)->with('photos')->first();

dd($product);
```

Output :

```
{
    "id":1,
    "title":"some product",
    "photos":[
        {
            "id":1,
            "path":"a photo 1 path"
        },
        {
            "id":2,
            "path":"a photo 2 path"
        },
        {
            "id":3,
            "path":"a photo 3 path"
        }
    ]
}
```

**The issue** when i try to access `$product->photos` i get nothing. just like an empty key.

If i try to `dd($product->photos)` i get `null`

The array key exists and containing data, why when accessing it, it returns nothing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the problem. it's a conflict

I was having column called **photos** in `products table` and it's same as the relationship name :

```
public function photos() { // this photos name
    return $this->hasMany(Photo::class, 'product_id');
}
```

so when i was trying to access **photos** it was calling the column **photos** not the relashionship name, and the column was empty and that's the cause it was always returning nothing.

Thanks.